# Java - copying arraylist objects

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I am trying to copy the contents of an arraylist into another object. I tried initializing the new ArrayList object in the following ways

```
newArrList.addAll(oldArrList);
```

and

```
newArrList = new ArrayList(oldArrList);
```

But every time I make a change to one of the array lists, the value also changes in the other ArrayList.

Can someone please tell me how I can avoid this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `ArrayList` will only contain references to objects - not the objects themselves. When you copy the contents of one list into another, you're copying those references. That means the two lists will refer to the same objects.

I suspect that when you say you make a change to one of the lists, you actually mean you're making a changed to one of the objects *referenced* by the list. That's to be expected.

If you want the lists to have references to independent objects, you'll need to make a *deep copy* of the objects as you copy them from one list to another. Exactly how that works will depend on the objects you're copying.

Comment: Hello, by `deep copy`, do you mean that the objects/contents should be copied one by one?

Comment: @user1282407: Yes. Instead of keeping references to existing objects, you make new objects with the same contents (except for immutable objects, where it doesn't matter).

Comment: Okay. Thanks! I guess there isn't an easier way to copy contents only. .